# Count distinct records but exclude current column value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the table called "tv_data" stored in BigQuery:

| Id | Channel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FOX |
| 1 | NBC |
| 1 | CBS |
| 2 | FOX |
| 3 | TNT |
| 4 | ABC |
| 5 | FOX |
| 6 | FOX |
| 7 | TNT |
| 8 | TNT |
| 4 | CW |
| 4 | FOX |
| 3 | CW |

I would like to get the number of distinct IDs by channel, but only those that are present within the given channel. I know how to do it row by row with this query:

```
SELECT channel, COUNT(distinct id) AS num_ids_only_in_channel FROM tv_data WHERE channel = 'FOX' and id NOT IN  (SELECT id from tv_data WHERE channel <> 'FOX') GROUP BY channel
```

In this case the output is:

| Channel | num_ids_only_in_channel |
| --- | --- |
| FOX | 3 |

Since only IDs '2', '5' and '6' have 'FOX' as their only channel.

Now I would like to do the same but for all channels without manually altering the WHERE clauses and running the query for every channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select channel, count(*)
from (select id, min(channel) as channel
      from tv_data
      group by id
      having count(*) = 1
     ) t
group by channel;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want a distinct count of ids per channel but only include those ids not shared by multiple channels

```
select channel, 
       count(distinct id) as num_ids_only_in_channel 
from tv_data
where id in (select id from tv_data group by id having count(distinct channel)=1) 
group by channel;
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much. Also runs way faster than the query I initially used.